# .NET XML Parser: Default attribute can not be applied as the attribute namespace is not mapped to a prefix in the instance document

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, attributes, default

I'm having a problem with .NET XML parser. When parsing a DITA document, the parser should add a default attribute value in a namespace of it's own, but when the namespace is not declared in the document, the parser throws an exception:

```
Default attribute 'http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/:DITAArchVersion' 
    for element 'topic' could not be applied as the attribute namespace 
    is not mapped to a prefix in the instance document.
```

Here's a minimal sample topic that shows the behaviour...:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<topic xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" id="so1" 
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:oasis:names:tc:dita:xsd:topic.xsd">
    <title>StackOverflow!</title>
</topic>
```

Documents like this work fine in other environments, which leads me to thinking that we must somehow be missing something in the parser configuration. This is how the document is currently parsed:

```
XmlReaderSettings settings = new XmlReaderSettings();
if (validate) {
    settings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessInlineSchema;
    settings.ValidationFlags |= XmlSchemaValidationFlags.ProcessSchemaLocation;
    settings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(
        delegate(Object sender, ValidationEventArgs args) {
            throw new Exception("Validation error for document " + 
                                pathinfo + ": " + args.Message);
        });
}
settings.DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit;
settings.XmlResolver = new CatalogXmlResolver(/*...*/);

XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(new MemoryStream(data), settings);

XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
if (!validate) { doc.PreserveWhitespace = true; } 
doc.XmlResolver = getCatalog();
doc.Load(reader);
```

How can I tell the parser to also add the corresponding namespace as it adds the default attribute?

Edit: Here's the stack trace:

```
Void <parseDocument>b__0(System.Object, System.Xml.Schema.ValidationEventArgs) System.Exception: Validation error for document /temp/Untitled1.xml: Default attribute 'http://dita.oasis-open.org/architecture/2005/:DITAArchVersion' for element 'topic' could not be applied as the attribute namespace is not mapped to a prefix in the instance document.
 at (...)
 at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(XmlSchemaValidationException e, XmlSeverityType severity)
 at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.SendValidationEvent(String code, String[] args)
 at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaValidator.GetUnspecifiedDefaultAttributes(ArrayList defaultAttributes, Boolean createNodeData)
 at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ValidateAttributes()
 at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessElementEvent()
 at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.ProcessReaderEvent()
 at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadNode(Boolean skipOverWhitespace)
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.LoadDocSequence(XmlDocument parentDoc)
 at System.Xml.XmlLoader.Load(XmlDocument doc, XmlReader reader, Boolean preserveWhitespace)
 at System.Xml.XmlDocument.Load(XmlReader reader)
```

...so it really is a validation exception; now, if I validate using "MSXML.NET" (whatever that is) in oXygen, it says that the document is valid, as with the other parsers.

Comment: You have shown C# code using the .NET framework classes in System.Xml. MSXML has nothing to do with .NET, it is a completely different XML package. As for the problem, can you show a minimal but complete XML document causing that error?

Comment: @MartinHonnen Ah, I stand corrected. I fixed the original question, and completed the sample document!

Comment: I am currently not sure how to set up the XmlReader to allow the default attribute from a different namespace. As you say that Oxygen validates with "MSXML.NET",  it might be worth asking in their support forum which .NET API they use in which way when you choose that option, perhaps they can share the code. I have tested that the legacy `XmlValidatingReader` does not seem to give that exception, on the other hand, it does not seem to add the default attribute either.

Comment: *Documents like this work fine in other environments*.  Is there a chance your [`CatalogXmlResolver`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.aspx) is resolving a different schema document in different environments?

Comment: Well, made another workaround for now. Instead of adding the namespace to the document instances, we found out that it helps to add an XmlNamespaceManager with the offending namespace added to the XmlParserContext that can be given to the Create method in XmlReader. 

If the required namespaces were read from the schemas using the catalog, this would solve the issue for real, but that would require parsing all the schemas in the catalog before parsing the document, and that'd be quite a load. 

If the parser did that, it'd suffice to parse just the schema it has to parse anyways.

Comment: I get this error when validating a really basic AIXM instance.
The xlink default attribute is not required, and so is not present in the xml so of course neither is the xmlns:xlink etc 
The dotnet validator still gives this error, even after adding the line as suggested above;
Dim XmlParserContext As New XmlParserContext(oXsd.NameTable, oNSmanager, Nothing, XmlSpace.None)
This to me really seems to be an error with the dotnet parser.
Stylus Studio using .Net parser validates ok..how?!
Note - I'm only using the nametable of the principal xsd; this should suffice though.